# Map Dynamic Json Key Value pair without dynamic or dictionary c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a json like below

```
{
    "date": "2021-12-04",
    "SMIFUND": {
        "ACC": 5.7299,
        "TATA": 5.155546,
        "RELIANCE": 108.779225
    }
}
```

now

```
SMIFUND ->  (input parameter to get this json result)
ACC, TATA , RELAINCE  ->  dynamic
```

Now as part of assignment I have to deserialize using `Newtonsoft.json` and cant use `Dictionary<string,float>` or `dynamic` but directly deserialize to either the whole json or the `SMIFUND` section .

My class structure below

```
public class Broker
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public List<Fund> funds{ get; set; }
    }

public class Fund
   {
       public string StockName{ get; set; }
       public float Price{ get; set; }
   }
```

I am able to break the result in two parts

```
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(result);

        brokerObject.Date = (string)jsonObject["date"];
```

but when I try to do List conversion to `Fund` , it gives a name value deserialization error

```
var fundsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Fund>>(jsonObject[$"{input}"].ToString());

{input} is SMIFUND
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general not using a Dictionary here would be a bad idea and not practical (IMO), but I assume this is for a school assignment, so this would be the way I would try to approach this.

In you example you are already using `JObject` which does work similar to a Dictionary so you could use it further like this:

```
public class Broker
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public List<Fund> funds{ get; set; }
}

public class Fund
{
   public string StockName{ get; set; }
   public decimal Price{ get; set; }
}

var input = "SMIFUND"; 
var json = "{\"date\": \"2021-12-04\", \"SMIFUND\": { \"ACC\": 5.7299, \"TATA\": 5.155546, \"RELIANCE\": 108.779225    }}";
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    
var brokerObject = new Broker() {funds = new List<Fund>()};     
brokerObject.Date = (string)jsonObject["date"];
    
var fundsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonObject[$"{input}"].ToString());
foreach (var x in fundsList)
{
    var fund = new Fund();
    fund.StockName = x.Key;
    fund.Price = Decimal.Parse(x.Value.ToString()); 
    brokerObject.funds.Add(fund); 
}
```

So basically instead of deserializing into a list directly, you deserialize into a JObject and iterate through that in the same way you would a Dictionary.

Assuming it is allowed to use JObject.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way would be to use a typed c# object for conversation:

```
    var jsonDeserialized=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BrokerD>(json);

    var result = new Broker
    {
        Date = jsonDeserialized.date,
        funds = jsonDeserialized.SMIFUND.Select(s => new Fund { StockName = s.Key, Price = (float)Convert.ToDouble(s.Value) }).ToList()
    };

public class BrokerD
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> SMIFUND { get; set; }
}
```

but if you prefer it slower, you can  parse  a json

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    
    var result = new Broker
    {
        Date = jsonObject["date"].ToString(),
        funds = ((JObject)jsonObject["SMIFUND"]).Properties()
        .Select(s => new Fund { 
        StockName = s.Name, Price = (float)Convert.ToDouble(s.Value)
        }).ToList()
    };
```

result

```
{
  "Date": "2021-12-04",
  "funds": [
    {
      "StockName": "ACC",
      "Price": 5.7299
    },
    {
      "StockName": "TATA",
      "Price": 5.155546
    },
    {
      "StockName": "RELIANCE",
      "Price": 108.77923
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It is stated in the header and in the body of OP - _"without dynamic or **dictionary**"_. I highly doubt that that changing the dictionary type from `<string, float>` to `<string, string>`  drastically changes things here.

Comment: @GuruStron I am sorry but OP  could state to make it without any code at all as well. I can see in his code " JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Fund>>" what is it do you think?